Why can't I Virtualize Ubuntu 24.04?
I have tried to Virtualize Ubuntu 24.04 with VirtualBox, and it does not start, the screen goes black, and after much insistence I start the graphics mode, but immediately it gets stuck, and it fluctuates between the two problems or the graphical mode does not start and if it boots at the moment it crashes, I have tried it many times and it always gives the same problems
I did it with Ubuntu 22.04 and everything works perfectly for me and I have been updated to 23.10 and it works perfectly, and it worked for me the first time

I don't understand what your issue is sorry; are you wanting to run Ubuntu 24.04 LTS as a VM within virtualbox?  as I have no issues doing that... however you've not said what Ubuntu 24.04 LTS you're asking about.. I'm a desktop user, thus I'm mainly running Desktop systems, but you maybe asking about Server? or something else as you've only mentioned a release, no architecture, product etc. details were provided. I know my HOST OS is setup to run 24.04 & is up to date; is yours?  etc.

I install Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop on a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox, but when I boot the screen is black and after much insistence on Restarting the virtual machine it drags Ubuntu 24.04 in graphical mode, but after a few minutes it hangs, I reboot it again and it does not boot, I have tried it many times and it always gives me the same problem.
This problem doesn't happen to me with UBUNTU 22.04, it works perfectly for me, My PC is an MSI 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12400F 2.50 GHz motherboard, 32GB of RAM and NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 1030 graphics card with 2GB of memory
